# JavaScript and AJAX not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the JavaScript and AJAX for signup form.

I want to post all textboxes in signup form through AJAX but am failing to do so.

signup.php

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('submit').click(function() {
    var first = $('#firstname').val();
    var last = $('#lastname').val();
    var Email = $('#email').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    var confirm = $('#confirmpassword').val();
    var phone = $('#phoneno').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "register.php",
      data: {
        (

          firstname: first,
          lastname: last,
          email: Email,
          password: pass,
          confirmpassword: confirm,
          phoneno: phone,

        )
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert('passed');
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("error");
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<title>
</title>

<div align="right">
</div>
<div id="div">
  <center>
    <h3>REGISTER</h3>
  </center>
  <table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Firstname</label>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required="">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Lastname</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" required="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Email</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Confirm password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" required="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Phone no</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="phoneno" id="phoneno" required="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="login.php">Login?</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

register.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
 $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
 $lastname= $_POST['lastname'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 $confirmpassword=$_POST['confirmpassword'];
 $phoneno=$_POST['phoneno'];
if($password==$confirmpassword)
{
$insertuser=mysql_query("insert into register(firstname,lastname,email,password,confirmpassword,phoneno) values('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password','$confirmpassword','$phoneno')",$conn)or die(mysql_error());
echo "success";

}
else
{
  echo "failure";

 }
?>
```

Comment: Why you are defining jquery two times?

Comment: try $('#submit') instead of $('submit').

Comment: try to remove the bracket in `data:{(` . it should be like `data:{}`

Comment: Remove the round braces () at your data property, since data is another object you only use curly braces {}

Comment: 1. You load jQuery twice 2. You have a form element called "submit" that is a very bad idea since it hides the submit event - however you do not have a form so the biggest mistakes are the two jQuerys and the lack of the # on the event assignment - also why are there () around the JSON

Comment: the PHP code is not relevant here.

Comment: To save stress, why don't you just serialize the form instead of defining each key element.  Also is submit an id or a class?

Comment: $('submit').click(function() change to $('#submit').click(function()

Comment: I vote to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: add a form in html and data will be 
data:$('#form_id_here').serialize() and on register.php get print_r($_POST) to show all data from form

Comment: @Nirajpatel there is no form

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong jQuery selector use

```
$('#submit')
```

To bind the button event

Also change the data passed in ajax - there should not be a () around it.

The code will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var first = $('#firstname').val();
        var last = $('#lastname').val();
        var Email = $('#email').val();
        var pass = $('#password').val();
        var confirm = $('#confirmpassword').val();
        var phone = $('#phoneno').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: {
                firstname: first,
                lastname: last,
                email: Email,
                password: pass,
                confirmpassword: confirm,
                phoneno: phone // no comma on the last item

            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('passed');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is correct  - not sure of the reason for the downvote, except for answering a typo type question

Comment: I would also rename the button. Never a good idea to call anything "submit" in case it ever ends up in a form

Comment: Why the dovnvotes? It is one of the first correct answers!

Comment: @mplungjan  Thank you for your suggestions and edits.

Answer (score 0):

**replace your data from jquery as follows**

```
data: {( firstname: first,
          lastname: last,
          email: Email,
          password: pass,
          confirmpassword: confirm,
          phoneno: phone,
        )
      }
```

**remove the `()`**

```
data:{
   firstname: first,
   lastname: last,
   email: Email,
   password: pass,
   confirmpassword: confirm,
   phoneno: phone
}
```

Comment: we have paas as json object

Comment: @mplungjan I think he mentioned the code from Q in the first part

Comment: @mplungjan I mean the first code block is from Q. he want OP to replace it with his line below.

Comment: @SagarV - already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44450541/295783 which for some reason gets voted down

Comment: I didn't noticed that. moved to top.

Comment: The first 3 comments to the question answered the question fully

Answer (score -1):

hey please replace your jquery code's 2nd line to

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: No need. The button is a button

Answer (score -2):

Input type should be submit like:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
```

if you want to use `$('submit')` else you need to change it to $('#submit').

Comment: He use a click event handler to submit the form using ajax

Comment: There is no form and NEVER use name="submit"

Comment: Your change made it even wronger. To use $("submit") you need `<submit .../>`